# C# WPF, how to open excel book in document viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I hope someone can help me how to open excel file in `DocumentViewer` component in wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DocumentViewer` does not support opening Excel documents directly. You will have to convert it to XPS first. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WordToXps09242009101005AM/WordToXps.aspx) which illustrates how you could use Office Interop in order to convert the document to XPS.